# How to render a view from a click in AngularJS with express or ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, router

I have this tree view, and what I want to do is when the user click an item, the page redirects to the item detail.

How I could do that? How can I pass the bindings to the page?
Do I need to use `angular-ui-router`? Or could I do it on `express`?

[image: treeView]

**hotel.module.js**

```
(function (){

  'use strict';

    angular
      .module('hotelsResult', []);

})();
```

**item-list.component.js**

```
(function (){

  'use strict';


  angular
      .module('hotelsResult')
      .component('itemList', {
        controller: itemListController,
        bindings: {
            hotels: '<',
            filters: '<'
        },
        templateUrl: "hotel-result/item-list/item-list.html"
      });

      function itemListController (){
        let self = this;
        let slicehotel = [];
        this.loadMore = function () {
          debugger;
          self.hotels = this.hotels;
        }
      }
})();
```

**item.component.js**

```
(function (){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('hotelsResult')
    .component('item', {
      controller:HotelItemController,
      bindings: {
          item: '<'
      },
      templateUrl: "hotel-result/item-list/item/item-component.html"
    });

    function HotelItemController(){


    }

})();
```

And then I want to have a view of the item that has more info. 
Like when you enter to a page like amazon and you click to show more detail of the product.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Part of an MCVE is listing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it -- people aren't going to want to type out your code manually! ;) It would also be helpful to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)